# In Internet Explorer 10, are developer tools not available from [F12]? If so, how do I access them?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

With metro IE 10 for windows 8, I assumed that I could use <kbd>F12</kbd> to open developer tools, just like it was possible in every IE since 8.

However, in windows 8 that doesn't seem to do anything - has it been removed or is it accessible in another way?

Comment: Are you running IE10 as the desktop version or the Metro app?

Comment: @DanielB metro app - it works while in the desktop version

Comment: I believe that the developer tools have been disabled for the metro version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it has not been removed. The Developer Tools only show up in the Desktop version, not the Metro version.

Comment: How do you get the desktop version?

Comment: Run iexplore.exe

Comment: Could you explain more about this silly Microsoft marketing jargon, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can always still use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: Welcome to the SuperUser site. This question is related to Internet Explorer, Firebug is for Firefox.

Comment: @wonea Firebug Lite is browser-independent. See here: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not available for Metro applications but should still work for Desktop applications.

As an alternative you might want to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) instead which allows you to at least debug the traffic happening between the Metro browser and the internet. For rendering, it should suffice to check the Desktop version of the browser as they share the renderer, and also have the same JS engine.

Comment: Not only most likely.

Comment: @Joey: True, was thinking in my mind if there were things that map to Metro itself but I highly doubt it.

Comment: fiddler is fairly useless (can't handle encrypted traffic without invasive workarounds) - I'm going to try [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), which at least does some minor inspecting

Comment: @Razor: Why would you use encrypted traffic *while* developing a website? And yeah, in-website extensions can help.

Comment: @TomWijsman to have an environment that most closely resembles production. Security warnings come to mind...